# Share model in frontend and backend

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, architecture, google-cloud-functions

Me and a pal are working on an app using flutter as our frontend framework and TypeScript/cloud functions as our backend. Our frontend model-class library has grown quite big and a large portion of it is needed on the backend. On the backend, the code is probably gonna become quite extensive too so we feel it is important to have type-safety and make sure our model can be upgraded smoothly. My intuition is to not want to code a copy of our frontend library on the backend in typescript. We have looked into google protobuf in order to have 1 code base for backend and frontend, but felt discourage since it seemed not many used it for our intended purpose. Ideally we would like to enforce the same variable names and types on frontend and backend. Are we trying to over-optimize and should we just re-code the parts we need from our frontend to our backend? How do people usually solve this? Appreciate any advice :)

Comment: While not code sharing per se, as you have different languages each side you could explore code generation techniques instead.

For example using something like Swagger to annotate your models, you can use a tool like Swagger Codegen to generate client side models and APIs/Services from your annotations in a different language, plus you get the benefit of a well documented API

Or similar to the Protobuf you mention thre are alternatives like Apache Thrift which allows you to define models as thrift objects which have models in different languages generated from them and serialised between

Comment: This question is an opinion based question. Please review StackOverflow's question asking guides.